# How to upload multiple files using Webflux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

How to upload multiple files using Webflux?

I send request with content type: `multipart/form-data` and body contains one **part** which value is a set of files.

To process single file I do it as follow:

```
Mono<MultiValueMap<String, Part> body = request.body(toMultipartData());
body.flatMap(map -> FilePart part = (FilePart) map.toSingleValueMap().get("file"));
```

But how to done it for multiple files?

PS. Is there another way to upload a set of files in webflux ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I already found some solutions.
Let's suppose that we send an http POST request with an parameter **files** which contains our files.

*Note responses are arbitrary*

1. **RestController with RequestPart**

   ```
   @PostMapping("/upload")
   public Mono<String> process(@RequestPart("files") Flux<FilePart> filePartFlux) {
       return filePartFlux.flatMap(it -> it.transferTo(Paths.get("/tmp/" + it.filename())))
           .then(Mono.just("OK"));
   }
   ```
2. **RestController with ModelAttribute**

   ```
   @PostMapping("/upload-model")
   public Mono<String> processModel(@ModelAttribute Model model) {
       model.getFiles().forEach(it -> it.transferTo(Paths.get("/tmp/" + it.filename())));
       return Mono.just("OK");
   }

   class Model {
       private List<FilePart> files;
       //getters and setters
   }
   ```
3. **Functional way with HandlerFunction**

   ```
   public Mono<ServerResponse> upload(ServerRequest request) {
       Mono<String> then = request.multipartData().map(it -> it.get("files"))
           .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
           .cast(FilePart.class)
           .flatMap(it -> it.transferTo(Paths.get("/tmp/" + it.filename())))
           .then(Mono.just("OK"));

       return ServerResponse.ok().body(then, String.class);
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi! This code seems to work for an array of files sent by the client. How can we do with a client that sent a flux of files? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate hashmap with Flux and return Flux

```
Flux.fromIterable(hashMap.entrySet())
            .map(o -> hashmap.get(o));
```

and it will be send as an array with filepart

Comment: I don't have to send any data, I have to receive.

Answer (score 1):

the key is use **toParts** instead of **toMultipartData**, which is more simpler. Here is the example that works with **RouterFunctions**.

```
private Mono<ServerResponse> working2(final ServerRequest request) {
    final Flux<Void> voidFlux = request.body(BodyExtractors.toParts())
        .cast(FilePart.class)
        .flatMap(filePart -> {
            final String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(filePart.filename());
            final String baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(filePart.filename());
            final String format = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);

            final Path path = Path.of("/tmp", String.format("%s-%s.%s", baseName, format, extension));
            return filePart.transferTo(path);
        });

    return ServerResponse
        .ok()
        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .body(voidFlux, Void.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

希望对你有帮助

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public JSON fileUpload(@RequestPart FilePart file)throws Exception{

    OSS ossClient = new OSSClientBuilder().build(APPConfig.ENDPOINT, APPConfig.ALI_ACCESSKEYID, APPConfig.ALI_ACCESSSECRET);
    File f = null;
    String url;
    try {
        String suffix = file.filename();
        String fileName = "images/" + file.filename();
        Path path = Files.createTempFile("tempimg", suffix.substring(1, suffix.length()));
        file.transferTo(path);
        f = path.toFile();
        ossClient.putObject(APPConfig.BUCKETNAME, fileName, new FileInputStream(f));
        Date expiration = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600L * 1000 * 24 * 365 * 10);
        url = ossClient.generatePresignedUrl(APPConfig.BUCKETNAME, fileName, expiration).toString();
    }finally {
        f.delete();
        ossClient.shutdown();
    }
    return JSONUtils.successResposeData(url);
}
```

Comment: Post an explanation in English, please…

Answer (score -1):

Following is the working code for uploading multiple files using WebFlux.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    Mono<Object> upload(@RequestBody Flux<Part> parts) {

        return parts.log().collectList().map(mparts -> {
            return mparts.stream().map(mmp -> {
                if (mmp instanceof FilePart) {
                    FilePart fp = (FilePart) mmp;
                    fp.transferTo(new File("c:/hello/"+fp.filename()));
                } else {
                    // process the other non file parts
                }
                return mmp instanceof FilePart ? mmp.name() + ":" + ((FilePart) mmp).filename() : mmp.name();
            }).collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));
        });

    };
```